# Sorting in aggregate group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Can I somehow sort data inside obtain by push in group?

I want to group the tournament by date - and sort years, that push tournaments inside group and sort them inside a group by date. And I don't have idea how to do it.

```
db.tournaments.aggregate([{$group : { _id : { year: { $year: "$date" }}, t: { $push: {_id: "$_id", date: "$date", place: "$place" }}}}], {$sort: {_id:
```

-1}})

This create a groups with tournaments, but does not sort anything in "t".

Comment: `_id` is an object, you shouldn't be sorting by `_id` but `_id.year` instead (assuming you want to sort only by year)

Comment: Unbelievable, but this works: db.tournaments.aggregate({$sort:{"date":-1}}, {$group : { _id : { year: { $year: "$date" }}, tour: { $push: {_id: "$_id", date: "$date"}}}}, {$sort:{"_id":-1}}).pretty()

Comment: That is "intentional". The order of output for the "grouped keys" is not in any specific order, but the `$push` items will **always** be in the order of discovery, so you do in fact need to `$sort` **first** where you intend a specific order. The aggregation framework has no methods to *"sort an array"*. So either 1. Sort first - best option. 2. `$unwind` the result array and `$sort` before grouping again. The second process would be commonly used with "sets", which also have no specific order.